# In PostgreSQL 9.6, what's the simplest way to expand a JSONB column filled with simple JSON dicts?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

Say, I have a table `json_table` with a JSONB column, `json_field`. Each element in this column is a single uncomplicated dict, e.g.,

```
{'first_field': 2 , 'second_field': 42}
```

Is there a way to create a new table were the dicts are turned into columns?

My current approach is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE normal_table ... first_field, second_field ... etc;
INSERT INTO normal_table (
    id,
    first_field,
    second_field,
    ...
)
SELECT
    id,
    json_field->>'first_field',
    json_field->>'second_field',
    ...
FROM json_table;
```

Is there a way to do something like the following?

```
SELECT
    id,
    expand_json_dict(json_field)
FROM json_table;
```

Or a similar succinct way of doing it? The JSONB column has a lot of fields I want to expand, and the queries become unwieldy. I've actually made a Python function which generates create/insert scripts. Still, I'd love for there to be a nice PostgreSQL way to do it.

Any thoughts?

**Edit**

The following is the working solution based on feedback here. Thanks guys.

```
drop table if exists json_table;
create table json_table (
    id int,
    json_field jsonb
);
insert into json_table VALUES
    (2, ('{"second_field": 43, "first_field": 3}'::jsonb)),
    (1, ('{"first_field": 2 , "second_field": 42}'::jsonb));

drop table if exists normal_table;
create table normal_table (
    id int,
    first_field int,
    second_field int
);

insert into normal_table
select (
    jsonb_populate_record(
        null::normal_table,
        jsonb_set(json_field, '{id}', id::text::jsonb)
    )
).*
from json_table;

select * from normal_table;
```

Comment: which version of postgres you run?

Comment: Our postgres version is 9.6

Comment: I'd go with `json_populate_recordset`, or `json_each_text`

Comment: Wouldn't I have to `CREATE type json_type AS (x1 float, x2 float, ...);` for that to work?

Comment: yes, or table to reference it's rowtype

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `normal_table` type as the base type to the `jsonb_populate_record` function:

```
create table normal_table (
    id int,
    first_field int,
    second_field int
);

with json_table (json_field) as ( values
    ('{"first_field": 2 , "second_field": 42}'::jsonb)
)
select (jsonb_populate_record(null::normal_table, json_field)).*
from json_table
;
 id | first_field | second_field                                                                                                                                          
----+-------------+--------------                                                                                                                                         
    |           2 |           42
```

If it is necessary to generate the `id` to be inserted use `jsonb_set`:

```
with json_table (json_field) as ( values
    ('{"first_field": 2 , "second_field": 42}'::jsonb),
    ('{"first_field": 5 , "second_field": 1}')
)
select (
    jsonb_populate_record(
        null::normal_table,
        jsonb_set(json_field, '{id}', (row_number() over())::text::jsonb)
    )
).*
from json_table
;
 id | first_field | second_field 
----+-------------+--------------
  1 |           2 |           42
  2 |           5 |            1
```

Comment: I found this one to be the best answer. But I'm not sure about the `with` part. Why is it there? I just removed it and things worked as hoped.

Comment: @AndréChristofferAndersen It is a CTE, common table expression. It is there just to have a sample table to fetch from in instead of the real one.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. And your final change to include `id` was perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a type (record) that reflects your keys and then use `json_populate_record`:

```
create type my_type as (first_field varchar, second_field varchar);

SELECT id, (json_populate_record(null::my_type, json_field)).*
FROM json_table;
```

If there are keys in the JSON document that are not present in the type, they are simply ignored. If there are fields in the type definition that don't have a match in the JSON document they will be `null`.